# Какое API оптимально, для решения нескольких задач

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть 3 задачи:

1. Вычисление расстояния между двумя координатами(необходимы данные в метрах/километрах)
2. Матрица расстояний
3. Прокладка маршрута из пункта А в пункт В в Яндекс Навигаторе

Сервис "**Матрица Расстояний и Построение Маршрута**" позволит осуществлять все описанные мною операции?
[image]

Если нет, какие сервисы необходимы для каждого из пунктов? Нигде не могу найти саппорт по решению данного вопроса...
Спасибо!

Comment: Вычисление расстояния между двумя координатами(необходимы данные в метрах/километрах) по дорогам или напрямую?

Comment: Прокладка маршрута из пункта А в пункт В в Яндекс Навигаторе формирование ссылки для яндекс навигатора или как?

Comment: 1. По дорогам
2. Пользуюсь ru.yandex.yandexnavi.action.BUILD_ROUTE_ON_MAP с параметрами "lat_from", "lon_from", "lat_to", "lon_to"

Comment: Ну тогда первые два пункта можно выполнить через "Матрица Расстояний и Построение Маршрута" а последний вы и так выполняете через ru.yandex.yandexnavi.action.BUILD_ROUTE_ON_MAP

Comment: По последнему пункту - после 5 запросов, приложение не открывается с информацией исчерпанного бесплатного лимита запросов. И дает ссылку https://yandex.ru/set/lp/navigatorb2b/0/ 
Вот и пытаюсь понять, что это еще за ключ, на какую api?

Comment: На странице предоставленной вам написано что нужно заполнить форму для получения ключа. Вы её заполняли?

Comment: Пока нет, там требуются ссылки на appstore и play маркет, которых нет.
Пытаюсь найти хоть какую то информацию

Comment: Напишите на paid-api-maps@yandex-team.ru c полным описанием как вы будет использовать эту функциональность, количеством пользователей и запросов.